# Include module synopsis in docstring for sphinx autodoc

Tags: python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm using Sphinx `autodoc` to generate the documentation for a python module from the docstrings in the source. I know I can include a `:synopsis:` in the `automodule` directive, but that kind of defeats the purpose of using `autodoc`, which is to put all of the documentation in the docstrings.

So I tried adding a `module` directive to the file like so:

```
.. module:: MyModule
    :platform: Unix, Windows
    :synopsis: A simple module to provide frobnication functions.
```

But then I get a "SEVERE" warning about duplicate modules, because I'm declaring it and `autodoc` is declaring it too. In addition, doing it this way also sort of defeats the purpose of using `autodoc` in that I have to specify the module name, instead of letting `autodoc` figure it out from the filename (not a big deal, but if I decide to change the name of the module, I need to change it here as well).

I was hoping I could use something similar to the `moduleauthor` directive for this, something like `modulesynopsis` or just `synopsis` alone as a directive, but Sphinx doesn't seem to recognize either of these.

Does anyone know if it's possible to include the synopsis in the docstring when using `autodoc`?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/14361140/407651